# CSS to paint a required field while it is empty

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to use CSS to paint the required fields in a form, so the user knows that they must be filled. I also want the painting to disappear once the field has a value.

This is an example of what I've tried:

**CSS**

```
input[type="text"]{
    display:block;
}
input.required[value=""] {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
Name:<input class="required" type="text" name="Name" value="" size="20">
Phone:<input type="text" name="Phone" value="" size="20">
```

The required field is painted just fine, the problem is that the color doesn't go away once the field has a value.

Is there any way to make it work with pure CSS?

Comment: With new browsers: use the `:invalid` psuedo-selector and the `required` attribute.  In older browsers you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: @Matt Whipple: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @MattWhipple Thanks, it works like a charm on Firefox 18! Although I use a framework where I can easily assign a class to a field, but adding the required attribute it's not so easy. Do you think is there any other way without the *required* attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With new browsers: use the `:invalid` psuedo-selector and the `required` attribute. In older browsers you'll need JavaScript.

If your framework is getting in the way of adding an HTML5 attribute I'd question the framework (or look at updating the version), but you could always use a shim if needed with something along the lines of (assuming jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $(".required.").attr("required", "true");
});
```

Less than ideal, but simple enough that it shouldn't pollute the system.